# css updates not being changed on rails, think it's an issue with production.rb

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

Any changes I make in css are not being reflected when I simply save and refresh my localhost. Only way to make them show up is to rake assets:clobber and precompile the assets again, resulting in the css changes updating. But this takes an unnecessarily long amount of time for something that I just was able to save, refresh and view the changes.

I think the issue is something with my environment files, because I made some changes a little while ago and I honestly don't remember what. Let me know if something looks out of place.

Here is my production.rb file

```
Rails.application.configure do
  config.cache_classes = true

  config.eager_load = true

  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  config.serve_static_files = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?

  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier

  config.serve_static_assets = false;
  config.assets.compile = true

  config.assets.digest = true

  config.log_level = :debug

  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
end
```

development.rb

```
Rails.application.configure do

  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: 3000}

  config.cache_classes = false

config.eager_load = false
config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
config.active_support.deprecation = :log
config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load
  config.assets.debug = false

config.assets.digest = true
config.assets.raise_runtime_errors = true
end
```

Let me know if any more code is necessary to diagnose the issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your production.rb. When you are running on local rails uses development.rb not production.rb until specified.

Comment: well @c0de222, where would my issue originate from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything looks fine to me in development.rb

Try these commands and let me know which one works out for you.

In developement.rb do this and restart your serever.

```
config.assets.digest = false
```

If it still does not work try cleaning your assets.

```
bundle exec rake assets:clean
```

If this also does not work out then the issue might be with turbo links. Use this `data: { no_turbolink: true }` to fix the issue with turbo links.

Comment: lol I must've changed config.assets.digest to true at some point, because switching it to false made my css update as normal. Thanks very much.